# How to remove account from Office 16 for Mac without losing data?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016

I had a old work account in my Outlook for Mac 2016 and deleted it by going to Tools>Accounts then highlighting the account and clicking the minus at the bottom of the box. This removed the account including all archived emails which I did not appreciate because I still wanted a record of the old emails.

Now I have a different problem because I migrated to a different ISP and per some expert advice I set up a second copy of each email account but with the server info for the new ISP. The purpose of this was to avoid losing mail in the transition. Now the transition is complete and I am getting duplicates of every email. I would like to remove one of these accounts but fear if I make a mistake I will lose email in my inbox which I want to keep.

How can I safely remove an account without losing its archived email?

Comment: Not quite clear about how you setup the second copy of account, but you may consider backing up the Outlook items (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/export-items-to-an-archive-file-in-outlook-for-mac-281a62bf-cc42-46b1-9ad5-6bda80ca3106) before removing the account in case problems occur.